# Error when installing sharepoint server 2013 with trial license

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, installation

I encountered this problem when trying to install sharepoint server 2013 trial edition.

> Trial editions and licensed editions of Sharepoint, Project Server, and office web apps products may not be installed on the same server

A little background on what I have already done prior to this error

1. I installed exchange server and set up the active directory domain
2. I am using Windows server 2012 datacenter
3. I have installed sql server 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually removed the exchange server but it still didnt work but I later found this in this blog http://www.mice-ts.com/sharepoint-2010-licensing-issue/  and it worked perfectly

```
1. Run RegEdit
2. Browse to HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Office/15.0/Registration
   {90140000-110F-0000-1000-00000000FF1CE}
3. Delete LicenseType
4. Restart your install.
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to install the SharePoint Exchange and Domain on the same Server. It will cause alot of conflict.

I highly recommend use the Virtual solution, create 2 VMs(one for SharePoint and One for Exchange).

Also check this one, may help you.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/75a00f2f-89bd-4922-9af2-575dc2f0bd1a/can-be-install-exchange-server-2010-and-sharepoint-2010-on-the-same-server-without-any-conflict?forum=exchange2010

Comment: Yepp, I have had several VM:s end up non-functioning after installing exchange on the same server (for integration tests)