# How to install licenced SP13 and Project Server 13 trial on stand alone server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, project-server, licensing

I have one server with licensed SharePoint 2013 and I want to try Project Server 2013, I download trial version, try to install it and have error

> "Trial version of Project Server cannot be installed with licensed SharePoint"

I try make [such](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126530/error-when-installing-sharepoint-server-2013-with-trial-license) steps, but I have not folder {90140000-110F-0000-1000-00000000FF1CE}

[image]
How to resolve my task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't install Project Server 2013 Trail over Licensed Sharepoint 2013.Based on my tries, there is no a valid workaround that succeeded in this scenario!

**The available options,**

- Provide a license key for Project Server.
- Install SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise Edition trail then install Project Server 2013 Trail